# Closures with each and $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures

I have a list of item that I want to edit

```html
<form id="mainForm" action="machin_chose">
    <div><input name="field" value="chouchouette" /></div>
    <div class="modified><input name="field" value="trutruc" /></div>
    <div class="modified"><input name="field" value="machin" /></div>
</form>
```

and make ajax post on each modified item

```js
$('#mainForm div.modified').each(function () {
    item = $(this);
    $.post(
        $('#mainForm').attr('action')
      , $(this).find(':input').serialize()
      , function (data) {
            item.removeClass('modified');
        }
    });
};
```

Successfully posted items should get removed their `modified` class.
I tried to use a closure with `item` to keep the currently modified one.
But as it is asynchronous, `item` contains always the last modified one.

How can I retrieve the current posted item in the success handler ?

Comment: You forgot a `var` in the `item` declaration there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to scope the `item` to each iteration by using `var`.

```
var item = $(this);
```

Comment: Your first "var item" answer is the winner :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code is that you are not using the closure; the `item` variable is global as you don't declare it in the function.

Just change this:

```
item = $(this);
```

to:

```
var item = $(this);
```

Now each iteration in the loop has its own variable.

---

You can also use the parameters sent to the function, however then you have a reference to the DOM element, not a jQuery object:

```
$('#mainForm div.modified').each(function (i, item) {
  $.post(
    $('#mainForm').attr('action')
    , $(item).find(':input').serialize()
    , function (data) {
      $(item).removeClass('modified');
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: As a tip, place this string at the start of all your script files/script tags: "use strict" newer browsers will display an error when you do something like this, older browsers will simply ignore that string.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#mainForm div.modified').each(function (index, valueOfElement) {
```

Instead of using `this`, you can use the "valueOfElement" argument provided by jQuery's `$.each()` . Note, valueOfElement refers to the current object/string/etc in the collection being iterated through.

Comment: I've got to +1 this. I'm a proponent of *not* abusing `this` the way jQuery does with its iterators. Using the parameters is nicer, and closer to the way the native iteration methods work.

Comment: This is the best answer and it has my upvote. There is no point in creating a variable when one already exists.